# Does assigning and acquiring an object reference from multiple threads require synchronization code?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, garbage-collection, synchronization

Disclaimer: This code runs two threads continuously forever. Run at your own risk.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp126
{
    internal class AnyClass
    {
        private int _state;// = 0

        public AnyClass()
        {
            _state = 1;
        }

        ~AnyClass()
        {
            _state = 2;
        }

        public void TestState()
        {
            if (_state != 1)
                throw new Exception("Already finalized");
        }
    }

    internal class Tester
    {
        private AnyClass _any = new AnyClass();
        private object _sync = new object();

        public void Initialize()
        {

            //lock(_sync)
                _any = new AnyClass();

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }

        public void Test()
        {
            AnyClass any;

            //lock (_sync)
                any = _any;
                //  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-3Ch] 
                //  mov         eax, dword ptr[eax + 4] // What if a context switch happens after this instruction?
                //  mov         dword ptr[ebp - 40h], eax

            any.TestState();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tester = new Tester();

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    while (true)
                        tester.Initialize();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                    throw;
                }
            });

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    while (true)
                        tester.Test();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                    throw;
                }
            });

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Is it safe to assign and acquire an object reference from multiple threads without synchronization code?

Should the lock(_sync) statement not be un-commented in both cases to ensure that garbage collection is safe?

If not, what happens if there is a context switch after "mov eax, dword ptr[eax + 4]" and the GC collects the object referenced in eax. Then when "mov dword ptr[ebp - 40h], eax" finally assigns the object reference to variable "any", is it not possible for the reference to be invalid? I have run the code for 12 hours without the lock and observed no bad behaviour. Can somebody please explain how this works?

I used VS2017 on Windows 10 1909. Targeted .NET 4.71 and x86.

Comment: What are you trying to prove here? The *atomicity* of a reference?

Comment: The GC knows how to check registers - they are treated as GC roots. Basically: this isn't a problem. And no, it doesn't require synchronization.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to confirm absolute atomicity of a reference. I already know that you will not read or write a corrupted reference due to thread access collisions because the default alignment of all memory "structures" are a factor of the memory bus width, probably at least 8 bytes.

Comment: The `lock` statement not only synchronizes the access to shared resources between threads, it also adds memory barriers so that the changes induced by one thread are visible from the next thread. So by removing the locks you may not have atomicity problems, but you may open yourself to visibility problems. Locking is the safe option. Lock-free multithreading is fragile and risky.

Comment: Huge doubt that `_any` really gets collected before `TestState` is called. When the the marking phase starts, all threads are stopped and analyzed. At the moment, `_any` will be presented in the thread that calls `TestState`, therefore will avoid collection and finalization as won't be marked as “unused”.

Comment: The GC roots explanation is resonating with me. I need to understand more though. Does anybody know where the book excerpts are from in this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938186/gc-roots-misunderstanding

Comment: I found the book. It is called "CLR via C#, 3th Edition". It is not in the 4th Edition!